# How can I use AnimationEvent and SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class SwitchAnimations : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private Animator animator;
     private int index = 0;
     private static UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController controller;
     private UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorState[] an;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start()
     {
         animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
         an = GetStateNames(animator);
         AnimationEvent ae = new AnimationEvent();
         ae.messageOptions = SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver;
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
         {
             animator.Play(an[index].name);
             if (++index == an.Length)
                 index = 0;
         }
     }

     private static UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorState[] GetStateNames(Animator animator)
     {
         controller = animator ? animator.runtimeAnimatorController as UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController : null;
         return controller == null ? null : controller.layers.SelectMany(l => l.stateMachine.states).Select(s => s.state).ToArray();
     }
 }
```

I tried to add this two lines:

```
AnimationEvent ae = new AnimationEvent();
ae.messageOptions = SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver;
```

But still after pressing A few times i'm getting this 3 exceptions:

> 'Space_Soldier_A_LOD1' AnimationEvent 'RollSound' has no receiver! Are
>   you missing a component?
>
> 'Space_Soldier_A_LOD1' AnimationEvent 'CantRotate' has no receiver!
>   Are you missing a component?
>
> 'Space_Soldier_A_LOD1' AnimationEvent 'EndRoll' has no receiver! Are
>   you missing a component?

And when in the Hierarchy on the **`Space_Soldier_A_LOD1`** I make **`Window > Animation`** I can't change/edit the animations and events. I see a message:

> Please select a gameobject that does not have 'Optimize Game Objects'
>   applied.

I didn't understand what to do.

So then I tried to add this two lines to the script with the `AnimationEvent` but it didn't solve it. How can I solve this 3 exceptions?

My main goal is to play all the states from the animator each time another state when pressing A.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to add this exceptions as methods in the script.
They can be empty but they should be there.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor.Animations;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwitchAnimations : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;
    private static UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController controller;
    private AnimatorState[] states;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        states = GetStateNames(animator);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            StartCoroutine(QueueAnim(states));
        }
    }

    private static UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorState[] GetStateNames(Animator animator)
    {
        controller = animator ? animator.runtimeAnimatorController as UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController : null;
        return controller == null ? null : controller.layers.SelectMany(l => l.stateMachine.states).Select(s => s.state).ToArray();
    }

    IEnumerator QueueAnim(params AnimatorState[] anim)
    {
        int index = 0;

        while (index < anim.Length)
        {
            if (index == anim.Length)
                index = 0;

            animator.Play(anim[index].name);

            AnimatorStateInfo si = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(index);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
            index++;
        }
    }

    private void RollSound()
    {

    }

    private void CantRotate()
    {

    }

    private void EndRoll()
    {

    }

    private void EndPickup()
    {

    }
}
```

You can also later if you want to put in this methods some stuff like in RollSound to place some audio clip.

But the idea is that this animations have events and instead starting messing with the events and animations just to add this methods.